# Property 'todos' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, rest, mean-stack

I am building my first MEAN stack to do app. I hope I am phrasing my question correctly because I am new to this.

The error is from my getList().subscribe function. I think I understand what the error is trying to tell me but I do not know how to fix it. I've tried assigning

```
todos: any;
```

but that didn't work. Then I've tried assigning

```
todos: Array<any>;
```

and a number of other different syntax; no luck.

dashboard.component.ts

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  user: Object;

  lists: any;
  todos: any;

  @Input() input;

  @Output() update = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService,
    private listService: ListService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLists();

    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
      this.user = profile.user;
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
  }

  getLists(): void {
    this.listService.getAllTodos()
      .subscribe(data => this.lists = data.todos);
  }
```

list.service.ts

```
export class ListService {
  newTodo: any;
  list: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllTodos() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/todos/lists');
  }
```

**EDIT**    ==================================================

This is my custom interface/class model I tried along with the changed coding for my subscribe to the observable

List.ts

```
export class List {
  item: string;
  completed: boolean;
}
```

The changed to my old files

dashboard.component.ts

```
import { List } from '../../list';

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  lists: List;

getLists(): void {
    this.listService.getAllTodos()
      .subscribe((data: List) => this.lists = data.todos);
  }
```

I still got the same error posted in the subject line except the type changed from 'Object' to 'List'

```
Property 'todos' does not exist on type 'List'
```

Comment: Please read documentation https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a custom **[`interface/class`](https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response)** to map the response. Or use type of any before accessing todos.

```
 this.listService.getAllTodos()
      .subscribe((data:any) => this.lists = data.todos);
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! That worked.  Before I contacted you again, I tried to make a custom interface/class model to map the response but the coding still gave me the original error. For my learning purposes would you b able to explain why my custom interface/class didnt work? I will post my code

Comment: you want me to explain here?

Comment: obviously your interface does not have  a field named todos

Comment: I posted my new interface model. Is that how it should have been?

Comment: no your todos should be another interface, which should be included in the List